# Why can't we set color in a col tag?

Tags: css, html, w3c

I've just ran into a use case where it would be useful to style a `col` tag:
[image]

In this particular case I wanted to set the `color` of the "Post Name" column but it turns out that it doesn't work or it is not allowed. But `background-color` is allowed though which makes me wonder why `color` is not.

I've checked the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-col-element) but I couldn't find any useful information. I know how to do the same effect with CSS only, I just wonder if anyone knows the reason why this happens to be like that?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nunoarruda/d8d7rans/

Comment: Can i see any code of the col tag? The image didn't show up for me...

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle example

Comment: You should include relevant code *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the diagram at [CSS 2.1 spec, 17.5.1 Table layers and transparency](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layers)

Columns are a layer in the rendering. so backgrounds of the layers above show through to the columns layer by default. Text on the other hand only applies to the cell, so only it can set the text color. Text color inherits by default though, so the cell can acquire its text color from an ancestor element. Col elements are never ancestors of cells.

The properties for which columns' properties apply are listed at [CSS 2.1 spec, 17.3 Columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns)

Comment: Congratulations on reading the whole question!

Comment: Super! Thanks! I didn't remember to look into the CSS spec since it was actually CSS related :/

Answer (score 2):

If you can use CSS3:

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    color: #CC0000;
}
```

That sets the color of every second `<td>` in a `<tr>`.

Comment: @ImagineWebDesign, and the answer by kbickar.

Comment: *“I know how to do the same effect with CSS only”* – the question

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that, but erred on the side that he may have meant doing something like adding classes to every td.

Answer (score 0):

col is for using the "span" attribute, you can't assign a color to a column (unlike a row).

The easiest way would be to add a class to each TD element in the column and assign a color to that.

Comment: It's a weird thing, in that you can set a background color with the col tag, but not a color.

Comment: *“I know how to do the same effect with CSS only”* – the question

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the color on the container above where you have the style currently at